# The text of a barcode is not the same as the text I used to generate it

Tags: java, pdf, itext, document

I generate a barcode from a piece of text. When I decode the barcode, the text is no longer the same. The position of a colon changed.

i.e.

```
    Name     : RAMACHANDRA
    Roll No : 1001
    Streem   : MCA
```

But my requirement is
below format

```
    Name    : RAMACHANDRA
    Roll No : 1001
    Streem  : MCA
```

This is my code

```
document.add(new Paragraph("NAME.   :"+" "+"RAMACHANDRA",fontH));                       
document.add(new Paragraph("Roll No :"+" "+"1001",fontH));
document.add(new Paragraph("Streem  :"+" "+"MCA",fontH));
document.add(new Paragraph());

code128.setGenerateChecksum(true);              
code128.setCode("1001");
code128.setSize(8);
code128.setBaseline(10);
code128.setBarHeight(40f);
code128.setN(3);
code128.setX(2f);

document.add(code128.createImageWithBarcode(writer.getDirectContent(), null, null));
```

Comment: Are you sure you use only space characters for the space between "Name" and ":" and between "Streem" and ":"? The symptom might be caused by tab characters instead...

Comment: Yes i have used only space

Comment: Did you count the number of spaces? Maybe you are displaying the text using a proportional font. You shouldn't true what you can see; you should count the number of characters programmatically.

Comment: @ allI have done this with below code:                                                               Document document = new Document();
document.open();
final  String[][] DATA = {{"NAME",":" +"Ramachandra"},{"RoLL No", ":" +"1001"}};
         PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2); 
        
          table.addCell(DATA[0][0]);
          table.addCell(DATA[0][1]);
          table.addCell(DATA[1][0]);
          table.addCell(DATA[1][1]);
document.close();   Its working fine

Comment: @PNayak can you be considerate enough to mark answers that helped you as accepted? You can do so by clicking on a check mark by the answer of your choice. That'll bring closure to your question and others may find your solved question helpful. I'd request that you mark answers as accepted on other questions you asked as well.

Answer (score 2):

Putting the content in a table solves the problem.

```
Document document = new Document(); 
document.open(); 
final String[][] DATA = {{"NAME",":" +"Ramachandra"},{"RoLL No", ":" +"1001"}}; 
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2); 
table.addCell(DATA[0][0]); 
table.addCell(DATA[0][1]); 
table.addCell(DATA[1][0]); 
table.addCell(DATA[1][1]); 
document.close();
```

Comment: Using a monospaced font (such as Courier) would also solve the problem. The OP doesn't seem to understand the concept of a *proportional font*.